# Create virtual forwarding email addresses using a server side programming language

Tags: email, forwarding

Some background information first before my question, I am curious as to what happens behind the scenes after you have purchased a domain name and then setup a forwarding email address from the newly purchased domain to forward to say Gmail for example.  This would be done using the website of where you purchased the domain name from such as GoDaddy, 123-reg and so on. They basically let you create a forwarding email address such as name@domain.co.uk, and then an email to where emails sent to this address will forward to such as name@gmail.co.uk.

I know what a "domain" is, and I know how domains are resolved to an IP address. I also know how email is delivered.

I was asking. My question was how are GoDaddy, 123-reg and so on configuring email forwarders by customers using a form on their website, what is happening behind the scenes.

My question is about the configuration of email forwarders by GoDaddy, 123-reg and so on. What happens behind the scenes when a customer of theirs submits a form with an email on there domain, and an email of where emails should be forwarded to that are sent to that domain. What are they doing and how are they doing it? For example are they configuring a file for a service, and if so how are they doing that when potentially multiple customers maybe adding email forwarders at the same time, how are they preventing corruption of the config file if that is what they are doing.

I'm guessing something must be configured on the email server maybe? and if so how would they be doing that with say a server side programming language when potentially several people are likely to be configuring forwarders at the same time. i.e. if a config file is being configured, how does the config file not get broken/corrupted by the same code trying to amend/add to it at the same time with it having been run by several users of the website at the same time, or near enough the same time.

I've only been able to find vague/generic information on what I already know about via Google such as the below for example :-

https://www.fused.com/docs/email/features/forwarders

https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/email/email-forwarding-explained

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know what a "Domain" is, and I know how domains are resolved. That wasn't my question! I also know how email is delivered. This also wasn't the question I was asking.

My question was how are GoDaddy, 123-reg and so on configuring email forwarders by customers using a form on their website, what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: you're literally asking how email is delivered, and you seem to be unaware as to the connection between the DNS and mail delivery (hint: usually, not a forwarding agent; that solution is a bad crutch). That's the point. Still, off-topic, as unrelated to unix/linux.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No I am not, I am asking how GoDaddy, 123-reg and so on are configuring email forwarders when customers submit a form with details of the email address on their domain, and an address of where to forward the email to.

I am not asking about DNS or how an email sent to an address on a domain gets to the forwarding address.

Comment: OK, tell me again how this is a UNIX / Linux question? We can't look inside their systems, and I'm pretty certain that (even if GoDaddy does actually provide a MTA, which, when I set up a domain > 10 years ago, which I don't own anymore, wasn't the case – they just correctly set up the MX record and mail directly went to Google's mailin server) a GoDaddy-sized solution will have nearly nothing in common with the Linux/UNIX system you might set up to do something similar for your own needs. So, this is not a question about software you're running on UNIX/Linux. This is speculation on

Comment: … email servers in general, and that's where this question loses touch with "software that runs on UNIX/Linux", because we're in the land of "hypothetical software, the concrete make irrelevant, which might or might not run on Linux/UNIX, the operating system being even more irrelevant".

Comment: So, maybe I'm just *misjudging* your question, and the question is not *how do godaddy et al. do that?*", but "*I want to implement an email forwarding service that  {please describe exactly what it needs to do}, on my {Unix/Linux OS} server. I have done {description} and now am facing {problem}, what do I do?*". Because *that* would be unambiguously on-topic!

Comment: Took back my vote and tried to address that!

Comment: I still don't see why this is relevant to U&L. There's no concrete request for assistance - it's all about _how to_... and _what if_...

Answer (score 1):

So, hopefully I got your core question right here:

> I want to know how large email service providers can add and remove users concurrently without corrupting the configuration files that contain said users? Configuration files on file systems that are inspired by / similar to POSIX will break when multiple processes write to them.

And the answer is: They don't use configuration files to store users.

It's really as easy as that. It's not a configuration file¹, but a database problem; so they just configure their software (or write / modify their software) to read user info from databases that allow for concurrent access instead.

In such large-scale installments as what you describe, there's the need to keep the user information up-to-date on many servers, running globally distributed – something you can't do with a shared file, anyway. So, databases, possibly sharded, with replication logic, being used by email infrastructure and user management software written in such a way that it knows how to get user information from said database.

It's very hard to know whether e.g. GoDaddy just uses a stock build of some common MTA internally – probably they aren't; at some point the configuration to solve your specific problem (caching emails for just long enough to deliver them) becomes so intertwined with your large-scale infrastructure that increasingly custom solutions need to be devised.

---

¹ Note that "file" on UNIXoids, Windows, BeOS and a lot of other OSes is not the only definition of the word "file": Mainframe OSes have "file systems" that look a lot more like key-value store databases and support exactly that.

Comment: Are they likely to be using POSIX? I know in the past email has been caught and blocked by their spam filters, and thus never arrived at the forwarding email address. I can't recall off the top of my head as to whether they released the false positive email that got blocked, or they did something else so when I requested it again it was delivered.

Comment: I honestly don't know. But as said, since most server operating systems are either mostly POSIX OSes (i.e. Linux, NetBSD, OpenBSD), or have very similar file access semantics, I guessed that's where your assumptions about breaking config files came from.